# On Android, JmDNS being called repeatedly with network ON and OFF

Tags: android, bonjour, zeroconf, jmdns

I am having a problem with using the JmDNS library for an Android app.

Since Bonjour does not send periodic keep-alive messages, I am closing and opening a new JmDNS instance every 30 seconds, so that I can have the serviceAdded and serviceResolved functions called.

But in between these instance creations, if I switch off and on the Wifi, although the creation of the JmDNS instance succeeds, my serviceAdded and serviceResolved functions are not called.

My main doubts are:

1) Is it ok to re-create these instance again and again and therefore effect a kind-of polling? Or is there a better way?

2) If the network is switched off and on, is there something I need to do each time I create the JmDNS instance?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
private void _startJmDnsService() throws IOException {

    if (mJmdns != null) {
        if (mJmDnsServiceListener != null) {
            mJmdns.removeServiceListener(mBonjourServiceType, mJmDnsServiceListener);
            mJmDnsServiceListener = null;
        }

        mJmdns.close();
        mJmdns = null;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "starting JmDNS");
    mJmdns = JmDNS.create(getInet4Address());
    mJmDnsServiceListener = new ServiceListener() {
        public void serviceResolved(ServiceEvent ev) {
            ServiceInfo serviceInfo = ev.getInfo();
            Log.w(TAG, "serviceResolved for device " + serviceInfo.getName());
        }

        public void serviceRemoved(ServiceEvent ev) {
            ServiceInfo serviceInfo = ev.getInfo();
            Log.w(TAG, "serviceRemoved for device " + serviceInfo.getName());
            CDevice.removeDevice(deviceId);
        }

        public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent event) {
            // Required to force serviceResolved to be called again
            // (after the first search)
            ServiceInfo serviceInfo = event.getInfo();
            Log.w(TAG, "serviceAdded for device " + serviceInfo.getName());
            mJmdns.requestServiceInfo(event.getType(), event.getName(), 1);
        }
    };

    mJmdns.addServiceListener(mBonjourServiceType, mJmDnsServiceListener);
    Log.w(TAG, "mJmdns Service Listener added!");
}
```

Comment: Hi rajath, I am also working on Android+jmdns. I am stuck with a issue. Can u help?

Comment: @KanakSony, I would suggest you post the question on StackOverflow, and maybe provide the link here in the comments. If I can, I'll help. If not, there may be others who might provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that might have a similar problem. There was nothing in the JmDNS library that had a problem. In my code, I was closing the multicast socket between instance calls, which was creating a problem.